# how can i get rid of space and amp inside of django template variable without using js or html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am not sure how to remove spaces and &amp in the django template variable. Actually I rendered a url string as django variable when I load a page.

But it automatically contains &amp and spaces.
After all, in html view, it is showed with &amp, % inside of the variable when I print it out in js console.

Of course, I can fix in js code by replacing them, but code will get messy
so I want to another way with python or django code.

any ideas to remove them in server-side?

Result:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?key=fff&ids=(1%,3%,4%,12%)
```

what I expect:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?key=fff&ids=(1,3,4,12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume in your context there is

```
context['url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?key=fff&ids=(1,3,4,12)'
```

If you want to get something as is, without any escaping, you can use the [safe template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

```
{{ url | safe }}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. eran. you are django expert! Awesome!